# How i get link product video in extra tab woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am developing website using wordpess and woocommerce plugin to upload product.
I am having a problem when I want to get a YouTube link according to the product (I have a description of it in the picture) to display it out for my own purpose.
So I have to do it to get it.
Please support me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13rHy.png)

I spent 2 days searching to see which variable it was stored in but failed. The problem is still there and I am in secret to implement it